# How to change css with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change dynamically my css properties. I know that the right way to do it is with: `document.getElementById("XXXX").style.fontSize = "xx-large";`

However, when I have this css:

```
#year1 .subdomain-text {
fill: #000;
font-size: 6px;
}
```

I haven't been able to find the way to access it, and I have tried any possible permutation (nothing works!):

```
document.getElementById("year1.subdomain-text").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
document.getElementById("year1").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
document.getElementById("subdomain-text").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
document.getElementById("#year1.subdomain-text").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
```

....

Any idea how to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: An example of the HTML elements you are trying to target and a description of which elements and how exactly are trying to change them would be helpful... the selectors you are trying to use make it confusing as to what you markup actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.getElemenByID()` which means you specify just the ID name no need to include the class name i.e. `document.getElementById("year1").style.fontSize = "xx-large";`

Example here :http://jsfiddle.net/Nb7wy/1770/

Comment: I already tried this. Unfortunately it changes the text inside year1, but not what it is contained in subdomain-text :S

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById retrieves html element by its id attribute. In your case, it should be:
document.getElementById("year1")

If the id is unique, as expected, the class is not necessary for the selector in the css rule either. You could just remove the class from your css rule.

For other cases where combining selectors is needed, it can be used document.querySelector(css_selector) (instead of document.getElementById).

Working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #year1 .subdomain-text {
    fill: #000;
    font-size: 6px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="year1" class="subdomain-text">Texto prueba</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="test();" />
    <script>
        function test() {
            document.getElementById("year1").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also tried this one, but unfortunately it didn't work either :S

Comment: I have added a example of working code to the answer @user3258465. It changes the font size when pressing the button.

Comment: if you want to change the style of **both** elements with id year1 **and** also elements with class subdomain-text, then the selector is **#year1, .subdomain-text** (#year1 .subdomain-text selects only the element with both id year1 and class subdomain-text)